# How to use partition name as a parameter in the select statement?

Tags: oracle

I have a huge table that I need to transfer into a new table, my resources do not allow me to that and I need to do that by chunking of data like this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE prod_tab IS TABLE OF dba_tab_partitions%ROWTYPE;
  products_tab   prod_tab := prod_tab();
  start_time  number;  end_time   number;
BEGIN

  SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO products_tab FROM dba_tab_partitions WHERE table_name = 'TBLX'

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE dba_tab_partitions2';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE tbl2';

  FOR i in products_tab.first .. products_tab.last LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML PARALLEL 24';
    INSERT /* PARALLEL(24) NOLOGGING */ INTO tbla2 NOLOGGING
    (
      "ID", datetime, ...)
    SELECT /* PARALLEL(24) NOLOGGING */ * FROM tbl1 PARTITION(products_tab(i).partition_name);
    COMMIT;

  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;
END;
```

Could anybody help me to correct it?

Comment: Could you provide an error message or other info about issues with current code?

Comment: You should use a execute immediate for the insert statement as well.

Comment: dear stepan the error message is:  ora-14108; illegal partition - extended table name syntax; ora-06512 : at line 19

Comment: If you like to copy **each** partition then make it simple and copy entire table, i.e. `INSERT /* PARALLEL(24) NOLOGGING */ INTO tbla2 NOLOGGING (...) SELECT * FROM tbl1;` Then you would also gain from `PARALLEL` hint.

Comment: What resources are forcing you to chunk the insert?  Once the hints are fixed, and direct path writes are used, the inserts shouldn't use much UNDO or REDO.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in my comments I think `PARALLEL` does not make any sense (but I am not sure about that) and running each partition one by one is also useless when you copy entire table.

Anyway, your code should work when you write it like this:

```
FOR i in products_tab.first .. products_tab.last LOOP
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML PARALLEL 24';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(24) */ INTO tbla2
      ("ID", datetime, ...)
   SELECT * 
   FROM tbl1 PARTITION ('||products_tab(i).partition_name||)';
   COMMIT;

END LOOP;
```

I don't know your requirements but maybe [Exchanging Partitions and Subpartitions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-E08650B4-06B1-43F9-91B0-FBF685A3B848.htm#VLDBG1156) could be an option for you.

Comment: Hi,thanks, it worked, but there is another problem, when cod reach to the END; line it did not exit and seems to make an unlimited loop.

Comment: Are you sure? I think it just takes much time. I don't see any reason for an infinite loop.

Comment: yes, i traced it in test window in pl/sql developer line by line, it inserted correctly, commited, ended loop, but on end line stoped for all night long and did not ended;

Comment: But then it is hanging, not infinite looping.