# FollowUp:How to use partition name as a parameter in the select statement?

Tags: oracle

Based on this post: [How to use partition name as a parameter in the select statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959197/how-to-use-partition-name-as-a-parameter-in-the-select-statement) I have tried to replicate it, but no success. I get error message "ORA-00922" Invalid or missing option. It must be something small syntax issue, but not sure where is it exactly. Here my code:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE PROD_TAB IS TABLE OF DBA_TAB_PARTITIONS%ROWTYPE;
  PRODUCTS_TAB PROD_TAB := PROD_TAB();
  START_TIME   NUMBER;
  END_TIME     NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT *
    BULK COLLECT
    INTO products_tab
    FROM dba_tab_partitions t
   WHERE table_name = 'LST_COLL';

  FOR i in products_tab.first .. products_tab.last LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE test_partition_copy
    PARALLEL NOLOGGING
    ("ID", datetime, ...)
      SELECT  *  FROM test_partition PARTITION (||products_tab(i).partition_name||)';
    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;
  COMMIT;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the PL/SQL variable to be injected via string concatenation; you're missing some single quotes:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE test_partition_copy
(id, datetime, ...)
PARALLEL NOLOGGING
AS SELECT id, datetime, ...
FROM test_partition PARTITION ("' || products_tab(i).partition_name || '")';
```

You also need the `AS` keyword; the `PARALLEL NOLOGGING` clauses come after the new table's column-name list; it's better to list the columns explicitly in both parts of the statement; and I've included double-quotes around the partition name just in case.

If you build up your dynamic statement as a string variable, you can inspect that (e.g. via `dbms_output`) to look for errors, or even try to run it manually to get a better idea exactly where the error is happening, depending on your client. You can then do `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE <string_variable>`.

You still have an issue in that you're trying to create a table with the same name - `test_partition_copy` - each time; the first time round the loop for the first partition you might create that table OK, but the second loop for the second partition will get an error because the table already exists.

Incidentally, DDL commits implicitly, so you don't need the explicit `commit`.

Comment: I see, thanks. I added the single quotes, but get same error message....